# how to perform full text search using sqlite fts3

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I have compiled the fts3 module for sqlite3.6.2. How to build the virtual table and perform search on some field of existent tables (like content:string in tweets)? Does ft3 support fuzzy search? (I checked the documentation but still remained horribly confused...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something as simple as this to search on 2 fields. You have to use unions.

```
string createSql = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TweetFts USING FTS3(TweetId, Title, Description)";

string insertSql = "INSERT INTO TweetFts (TweetId, Title, Description) 
     SELECT TweetId, Title, Description FROM Tweet";

string sql = @"select TweetId from TweetFts where Title match '" + allWords + "'";
sql += " union ";
sql += @"select TweetId from TweetFts where Description match '" + allWords + "'";
sql += " union ";
sql += @"select TweetId from TweetFts where Title match '""" + exactMatch + @"""'";
sql += " union ";
sql += @"select TweetId from TweetFts where Description match '""" + exactMatch + @"""'";
```

Run this query and you have a list of Tweet that match.

I don't see anything fuzzy other than the prefix search using *.

There is a soundex function.